# Publish-AzureServiceProject is not updating files on the cloud

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a PHP Azure project which I have to manage with Powershell cmdlets. One of these, Publish-AzureServiceProject doesn't seem to be detecting file changes so these are not updated on the cloud (even though no errors are displayed).

I have remote desktop'd into the machines and the code is definitely not updated from weeks ago.

If I deploy to the local emulator, it is fine but this is much more obvious because it displays "removing old package" and "creating local package". The cloud package definitely contains the latest files, so the packaging is working fine.

Can anyone tell me how to force the publish to update the files on the cloud and more importantly, why this is not happening? Also, if I force the update, will it deploy to a new box and get a new IP Address?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide exact PowerShell commands and parameters you are using (omitting sensitive information such as cloud service name, subscription id, passords, etc)

Comment: Publish-AzureServiceProject -Location "North Europe" -StorageAccountName xxxxx -Slot Production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work now.

I have removed and reinstalled azure libraries from my machine and created a new project from scratch and copied the original files over into it. I have not included diagnostics (not sure if that's an issue) and I have modified the Publish-AzureServiceProject script to select the subscription each time before it publishes.

It is possible that the subscription confusion was not helping (I have two Azure subscriptions and it might have used the wrong one at some point and done something weird) and also it was possible there was some conflict with various versions of the Azure SDK since I have been using it for over 6 months but at the moment, all is good.

A related article on my blog here: [Problems with PHP Azure](http://lukieb.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/php-azure-http-error-message-storage.html)

Thanks for the interest